# Is there a way to repeat a command for all rows of a column in `tabular`?

Tags: tables

I would like to write something like the following, so as to avoid having to repeatedly write the same thing for every row:

```
\begin{tabular}{cc{\begin{tikzpicture}#\end{tikzpicture}}c}
Object&Name&\draw(0,0)--(1,1)&\\
rows
\end{tabular}
```

Of course it could be anything instead of this particular `tikzpicture` environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED to show the use of other `tikz` commands besides `\draw`.  The leading macro must be protected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tikz}
\newcommand\pdraw{\protect\draw}
\newcommand\pcoordinate{\protect\coordinate}
\definecolor{orange}{RGB}{233,77,16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc>{\begin{tikzpicture}}c<{\end{tikzpicture}}}
Object&Name&\pdraw(0,0)--(1,1);\\
Object&Name&\pdraw(0,0)--(1,.5);\\
Object&Name&\pdraw(0,0)--(1,.25);\\
A&B&
    \pcoordinate (gNE)                  at (.5,.5);
    \coordinate (gSW)                   at (-.5,-.5);
    \coordinate (titleN)                at (0,.3);
    \coordinate (titleS)                at (0,.1);
    \fill [color=orange] (gSW) rectangle (gNE);
    \fill [color=yellow] (.3,.5) rectangle (0.4,-0.5);
    \shade [left color=black, right color=orange] (titleS -| gSW) rectangle (titleN -| gNE);
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, `\noexpand` could be used instead of `\protect`.

Comment: Why `tabularx` (no `X` columns), and not `array`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. The first package that comes to mind with support for `>` and `<` directives is `tabularx`, but you are right, `array` is the less invasive way.  I will edit.

Comment: I thought it's exactly what I wanted. But as I'm experimenting with it, it works for `\draw` but not for `\shade` say.

Comment: @Chrystomath, for `shade` and other `tikz` picture specifics features you need to load used `tikz` libraries.

Comment: @Chrystomath It works.  See my edit.

Comment: Great! I don't understand fully though. How do you know which commands you need to "protect"? When I tried with shade, latex did not recognise the command.

Comment: Is it the initial command that you need to protect?

Comment: @Chrystomath I am pretty confident that only the leading macro need be protected.

Comment: it is easier if user starts each tikzpicture cell by a  `\relax` , this avoids having to define (and force user to make use of) all those `\p...` things.